# Javascript regular expression unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="textbox" name="txtInput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
if (! document.form1.txtInput.value.match(/\bSun(il)? (Mishra)?\b/)){
    alert("Please enter valid value!");
} else {
    alert("Success!");
}
}
</script>
<input type="button" name="btnSubmit" onclick="validate()" value="Go" />
```

It gives success on **Sunil Mishra**, **Sun Mishra** but not for **Sunil** OR **Sun**. I tried entering the input with space, but that also doesn't work.

Is there some issue in the code?

Comment: remove the blank space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the space is optional, it needs to be in the second group too:

```
/\bSun(il)?( Mishra)?\b/
```

The reason adding a space at the end won’t work is because there’s no word boundary (`\b`) at the end of a string after a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\bSun(il)? (Mishra)?\b/
```

The reason this doesn't match `Sun` or `Sunil` on its own without `Mishra` is because of the space between the two names in the regex pattern.

The space isn't shown as optional, so the pattern will fail to match if the space isn't present, even though `Mishra` is optional.

To fix this, move the brackets around `Mishra` to include the space before it:

```
/\bSun(il)?( Mishra)?\b/
```

Comment: The pattern will not work even if space is added as pointed by minitech

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to add the space into the second group, as the other answers have pointed out, you can use: `/\bSun(il)?\s*(Mishra)?\b/`. This will allow more than one space, tabs, etc. while also keeping it out of the Mishra group's result.